# value saveToCassandra is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(String, Int)]

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Spark, I'm getting this error when i try to save data to cassandra. 
I have imported: StreamingContext._ and SparkContext._, but still get the error.

These are the dependencies I'm using:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2", 
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2", 
"com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.5.0", 
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.2"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use [`saveToCassandra`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.5.0/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/streaming/DStreamFunctions.scala#L43) on a `DStream` you have to import [`DStreamFunctions`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.5.0/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/streaming/DStreamFunctions.scala#L16) for example with:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._
```